# Application.Evaluate("<<positive number>>") throws application defined error

Tags: excel, vba

So in one of my projects I have an evaluator callback which offers me lambda-like syntax for dealing with arrays:

```
fMitPCInt = Mitigations.Filter(cbEqn, Eqn("$_::isInternal")).Map(cbMit, Eqn("$_.GetEFI(""" & sSeverityInt & """)"))
```

This essentially generates a callback which calls `Application.Evaluate` (innefficient I know but it's a nice syntax sugar).

Long and short of it is in Excel365 `Application.Evaluate("1")` throws an error. From testing I found the following:

```
Application.Evaluate("3")   'throws error
Application.Evaluate("2")   'throws error
Application.Evaluate("1")   'throws error
Application.Evaluate("0")   'works
Application.Evaluate("-1")  'works
Application.Evaluate("-2")  'works
Application.Evaluate("-3")  'works
Application.Evaluate("1+0") 'works
```

So essentially, `Application.Evaluate` just doesn't work for positive numbers in Excel365.

How can we get around this problem?

Comment: None of those errors for me.

Comment: @SJR Maybe it depends on the version of 365?

Comment: Possibly, which version are you using?

Comment: What exact error are your getting?

Comment: @SJR Version 1911 12228.20364    - 16.0.12228.20100 32-bit   - Not sure which of these numbers is the actual version. The 2nd set was from the "About Excel" section. The first were from the account page.

Comment: @JvdV Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: It went up from 1911 to 2003 over night and that fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution is to Replace `Application.Evaluate()` with an `EvaluateEqn()` function defined as such:

```
Function EvaluateEqn(ByVal sCode as string) as variant
    if isNumeric(sCode) then
        EvaluateEqn = CDbl(sCode)
    else
        EvaluateEqn = Application.Evaluate(sCode)
    end if
End Function
```

---

Edit: The more long term solution is to use a library I built for this and many other related issues with `Application.Evaluate()`. Use [`stdLambda`](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdLambda.cls)

```
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("2")()  '==>  2
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("1")()  '==>  1
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("0")()  '==>  0
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("-1")() '==> -1
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("-2")() '==> -2
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("$1+$2")(1,2) '==> 3
Debug.Print stdLambda.Create("$1.Name")(Application) '==> Microsoft Excel
```